# Integrate $\int \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}dx$ using $x = \cos(u) $

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to integrate $\int \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$ using $x = \cos(u)\Rightarrow dx = -\sin(u) du$

My attempts:
$$\int \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}dx=\int \sqrt{\frac{(1+x)(1-x)}{(1-x)(1-x)}}dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x}dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x}dx$$ 
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\sin^2(u)}}{1-\cos(u)}( -\sin(u))du=\int \frac{-\sin(u)^2}{1-\cos(u)}du=\int \frac{-(1 - \cos^2(u)) }{1-\cos(u)}du$$ , someone could help because i block here because i don't get the same resultat with [this website](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\sin^2(u)}}{1-\cos(u)}( -\sin(u))du=\int \frac{-\sin^2(u)}{1-\cos(u)}du=\int \frac{-(1 - \cos^2(u)) }{1-\cos(u)}du$$
$$\int \frac{-(1 - \cos(u))(1 + \cos(u)) }{1-\cos(u)}du=-\int (1 + \cos(u)) du=-u-\sin u+C$$

Can you replace the value of $u$ by  using $\cos u =x$

Answer (score 8):

$$\frac{1+\cos u}{1-\cos u}=2\cot^2\left(\frac{u}{2}\right).$$ 
So your integral is
$$\int\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\, dx=-\sqrt{2}\int \sin u \cot\left(\frac{u}{2}\right) \, du=-2\sqrt{2}\int \cos^2 \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\, du$$
Here we are using $\sin u =2\sin \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)$. Now once again we can write $2\cos^2 \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)=1+\cos u$ to complete the integral.

Answer (score 7):

Try this-

$$\int\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}dx=\int\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

The first integral is $\arcsin x$ and the second is evaluated by substituting $u=x^2\implies du=2xdx$

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways, and a natural temptation is to exploit the fact that $g(z)=\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ is an involution, $g(g(z))=z$. In particular
$$ \int\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\,dx = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{g(x)}}\stackrel{x\mapsto g(z)}{=}\int\frac{g'(z)\,dz}{\sqrt{z}}\stackrel{z\mapsto u^2}{=}2\int g'(u^2)\,du =4\int\frac{du}{(1+u^2)^2}$$
and the last integral is elementary. By partial fraction decomposition or IBP
$$ \int\frac{du}{(1+u^2)^2}=C+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{u}{1+u^2}+\arctan u\right) $$
and now it is enough to substitute $u=\sqrt{g(x)}$ in the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$$ then we get
$$x=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$$
$$dx=\frac{4t}{(t^2+1)^2}dt$$

Comment: i said using $x = cos(u)$